# Laravel blade template yield in child

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've a master layout like this:

```
<head>
    @yield('styles')
</head>

<body>

    @include('header')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
```

Now I've following structure in page content:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="page-content">
         @include('sidebarandfooter')
    </div>
@endsection
@section('copyright')
    @include('copyrightv2')
@endsection
```

Sidebarandfooter.blade.php have following:

```
 ...[CODE for sidebar]...
 @yield('copyright')
```

It's should be called inside `<div class="container-fluid"></div>` as I've different class of `div container` for different pages.
I'm not able to yield the copyright part. I've different copyright section for different pages. Is it wrong, how can we execute such kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunattely it's imposible in way you declare it because this section:

```
@section('copyright')
    @include('copyrightv2')
@endsection
```

been loaded before you call this: `@include('sidebarandfooter')` with `copyright` section inside.

What you can do is to pass a key as a parameter to view to the included page content partial like this:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="page-content">
         @include('sidebarandfooter', ['copyrightsView' => 'copyrightv2'])
    </div>
@endsection
```

and then just call inside `Sidebarandfooter.blade.php` in the include:

```
...[CODE for sidebar]...
@include($copyrightsView)
```

Comment: Hi! I've  upsdate my entry. I saw that I made a mistake on the last line shiuld be: `@include($copyrightsView)`

Comment: Yes, I was about to tell. Anyways that `key parameter` part really worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change your master layout like

```
<head>
    @yield('styles')
</head>

<body>

    @include('header')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
    @yield('copyright')
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
```

since i am not seeing a `section` for copyright in your `master` layout

Comment: problem is with the div. it should be called inside `<div class="page-content"></div>` tag

Comment: will `<div class="page-content"></div>` going to be same throughout all the pages?